# How to add textview on Imageview using bitmap drawable in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, picasso, android-bitmap

## Task

1) Download the image from repository using picasso library

2) Add text and Image on specific coordinates on downloaded image. I don't want to use `RelativeLayout`. Can we do it using `bitmap` , `canwas`, `drawable`?

3) After adding Text and Image on specific coordinates load the Image on `ImageView` specified in `Picasso.load()` section [Please have a look at the code below].

How can I do that?

Example (Look at the heart and amount)
[image]

I am using `picasso` to download images:

```
private Target loadtarget;

public void loadBitmap(String url) {

if (loadtarget == null) loadtarget = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        // do something with the Bitmap
        handleLoadedBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed() {

    }
}

Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(loadtarget);
}

public void handleLoadedBitmap(Bitmap b) {
// do something here
}
```

my `ImageView.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

Now I want to add `text` or `image` on above image (loaded by picasso) using `bitmap` and `canvas`. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried to use LinearLayout?  Set image as layout background,  textview can be added on the bottom-left and heart on the top-right?

Comment: Design a template that matches your need either statically using XML or programmatically and just set values to each view

Comment: As @Want2bExpert said, it would be easier if you create a layout match your need instead of create an image. An image will not adapt to different screens (size and resolution).